# How To Remove All Odd Numbers In An Array Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone debug this code? I cannot for the life of me find the (run-time) error:

```
function generate_fibonacci(n1, n2, max, out){
    var n = n1+n2;
    if(n<max){
        out.push(n);
        generate_fibonacci(n2, n, max, out);
    }
}

function generate_fibonacci_sequence(max){
    var out = [1];
    generate_fibonacci(0, 1, max, out);
    return out;
}

function remove_odd_numbers(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(!(arr[i]%2==0)){
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function sum(array){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total+=array[i];
    }
    return total;
}

var fib_sq = generate_fibonacci_sequence(4000000);

console.log("Before: " + fib_sq);

remove_odd_numbers(fib_sq);

console.log("After: " + fib_sq);

console.log("WTH?: " + remove_odd_numbers([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]));
```

Output:

```
Before: 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946,17711,28657,46368,75025,121393,196418,317811,514229,832040,1346269,2178309,3524578
After: 1,2,5,8,21,34,89,144,377,610,1597,2584,6765,10946,28657,46368,121393,196418,514229,832040,2178309,3524578
WTH?: 2,4,6,8
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

I'm going crazy or something. For some reason, all odd numbers are not being removed. But as you can see at the end, it works perfectly. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: For my fib_sq, all odd numbers are not being removed. Look at the output, specifically "After." Can you run the code?

Comment: You're talking about a (run-time) error; typically that refers to an error thrown by JavaScript itself. I think what you meant is that you get an unexpected result.

Comment: Ah, I appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in the original code is that when you remove the first `1` at index 0, the array gets shifted; now  `arr[i]` is contains the second `1`; but you just step over it.

You need to use while instead of if here, or copy to a separate list. This is an example for splicing:

```
function remove_odd_numbers1(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // here
        while (arr[i] % 2) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

But it will be slow though. Better to create a new array:

```
function remove_odd_numbers2(arr){
    var rv = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (! (arr[i] % 2)) {
            rv.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Generally the best algorithm however is to use the same array, if the original is not needed, so that no extra memory is required (though on javascript this is of a bit dubious value):

```
function remove_odd_numbers3(arr){
    var out = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (! (arr[i] % 2)) {
            arr[out++] = arr[i]; 
        }
    }
    arr.length = out;
    return arr;
}
```

Notice however that unlike the splice algorithm, this runs in `O(n)` time.

Also, the Array.prototype.filter() is not bad, being a builtin. It also creates a new array and thus is comparable to the 2.

Comment: You don't need an inner loop, and you don't need to make a copy. All that's needed is to either iterate in reverse or adjust the index, both of which would be preferred solutions.

Comment: The thing is, reverse splicing will still be slow. The index adjustment works.

Comment: What is "index adjustment"?

Comment: @user2316667: decrement `i` every time you do a splice. @Antti: Why would iterating in reverse be slow? Anyway, if performance was a concern, then the adjacent splices should be batched.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, `if (arr[i] % 2)` is wrong, it will return all odd numbers.

Comment: crazy train: splice will always be slower, as it pushes the complexity of the algorithm into O(n^2).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Oh, you mean slower than the `.push()`. Trouble is that it doesn't actually remove anything, as the method name suggests.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, Good point, I agree that the name could suggest it's modifying the initial object. However, how would you name a method that's not? I think you just have to be aware of the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a really simple, fast way to do it. Using your data, it only took 48ms to complete. Hope this helps..

```
function noOdds(values){
  return values.filter(function (num) {
    return num % 2 === 0;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about this, however I doubt using `splice` is efficient compared to creating a new array.

```
function remove_odd_numbers(arr) {
    var notOdd = [],
        i = 0,
        len = arr.length,
        num;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        !((num = arr[i]) % 2) && notOdd.push(num);
    }

    return notOdd;
}
```

EDIT: You should probably use the native [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function, as suggested by @Jack. I leave this answer as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Because `splice()` modifies the array, your index will be off in the next iteration; you need to either decrease the loop variable, use a `while` loop like Antti [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18305442/1338292) or iterate backwards like Crazy Train [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305431/how-to-remove-all-odd-numbers-in-an-array-using-javascript#comment26860207_18305442).

That said, the use of `splice()` is awkward to work with because it modifies the array in-place. This functionality can be easily accomplished using a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function as well:

```
function remove_odd_numbers(arr) 
{
    return arr.filter(function(value) {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    });
}
```

This creates and returns a new array with only the even values.

Given the recency of this function, check the [compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) how to handle browsers IE < 9. Many popular libraries, such as jQuery, underscore, etc. take care of this for you.

**Update**

Instead of filtering the array afterwards, it would be more memory efficient to only add the even values as you perform the recursion:

```
function generate_fibonacci(previous, current, max, callback)
{
    var next = previous + current;

    if (next < max) {
        callback(next);
        generate_fibonacci(current, next, max, callback);
    }
}

function generate_fibonacci_sequence(max, callback)
{
    callback(1);
    callback(1);
    generate_fibonacci(1, 1, max, callback);
}

var out = [];
generate_fibonacci_sequence(4000000, function(value) {
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        out.push(value);
    }
});
```

Instead of passing the `out` array, I'm passing a function to be called whenever a new sequence value is generated; the filtering is done inside that callback.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 version from "Tabetha Moe" answer

```
function noOdds(arr) {
    return arr.filter(value => value % 2 === 0);
}
```