# What is the in-place alternative to Array.prototype.filter()

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I've got an array that I would like to remove some elements from. I can't use `Array.prototype.filter()`, because I want to modify the array in place (because it saves a memory allocation and, more important for me, makes the code more simple in my use case). Is there an in-place alternative to `filter` that I can use, maybe analogously to how [`Array.prototype.forEach()` can be used as an in-place variant to `Array.prototype.map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034430/371137)?

Edit: Minimum example upon request:

```
function someCallback(array) {
  // do some stuff
  array.filterInPlace(function(elem) {
    var result = /* some logic */
    return result;
  })
  // do some more stuff
}
```

Comment: @Arg0n: Nope, the variable that I would have to assign to is outside of my current scope.

Comment: Can you show the minimal amount of code needed to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Your assumption that a memory allocation is somehow so expensive that it must be avoided should be re-examined. It is hardly likely to be a problem unless you are dealing with a million arrays. Can you sketch out the logic under which the code is simpler with a non-mutating approach?

Comment: @torazaburu: Well, no, that's the problem. Using an immutable approach would require me to rewrite a lot of existing code or use a really ugly (i.e. difficult to understand) work-around. Before I do that, I'll remove the elements by hand.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Is there an in-place alternative to filter

No, but it's not hard to write your own. Here is an approach which squeezes out all the values which fail a condition.

```
function filterInPlace(a, condition) {
  let i = 0, j = 0;

  while (i < a.length) {
    const val = a[i];
    if (condition(val, i, a)) a[j++] = val;
    i++;
  }

  a.length = j;
  return a;
}
```

`condition` is designed to have the same signature as the callback passed to `Array#filter`, namely `(value, index, array)`. For complete compatibility with `Array#filter`, you could also accept a fourth `thisArg` parameter.

#### Using `forEach`

Using `forEach` has the minor advantage that it will skip empty slots. This version:

- Compacts arrays with empty slots
- Implements `thisArg`
- Skipps the assignment, if we have not yet encountered a failing element

```js
function filterInPlace(a, condition, thisArg) {
  let j = 0;

  a.forEach((e, i) => { 
    if (condition.call(thisArg, e, i, a)) {
      if (i!==j) a[j] = e; 
      j++;
    }
  });

  a.length = j;
  return a;
}

a = [ 1,, 3 ];
document.write('<br>[',a,']');

filterInPlace(a, x=>true);
document.write('<br>[',a,'] compaction when nothing changed');

b = [ 1,,3,,5 ];
document.write('<br>[',b,']');

filterInPlace(b, x=>x!==5);
document.write('<br>[',b,'] with 5 removed');
```

Comment: Nice touch only resizing the array once. I like it. I actually never knew you could assign a value to the `length` property to produce an effect.

Comment: This answer uses the same algorithm as the highest voted answer to [*How To Remove All Odd Numbers In An Array Using Javascript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18305442/257182)

Comment: Edited to correct this answer. filterInPlace() truncated additional values in Arrays with holes.  [See the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/apy76q9x/8/).  The obvious [fix failed](https://jsfiddle.net/apy76q9x/12/), too.  However [this variant](https://jsfiddle.net/apy76q9x/18/) seems to work.

Answer (score 32):

You could use the following:

```
array.splice(0, array.length,...array.filter(/*YOUR FUNCTION HERE*/))
```

Explanation:

- Splice acts in place
- First argument means we start at the start of the array
- Second means we delete the entire array
- Third means we replace it with its filtered copy
- The ... is the spread operator (ES6 only) and changes each member of the array into a separate argument

Comment: It's not doing the filtering in-place though... its filtering in a separate array, empties the original, and then copies the filter results into the emptied original. Doesn't save on memory allocs as OP desires.

Comment: It's still useful due to the fact that it preserves the original reference to the array object instead of changing the reference to some other array.

Answer (score 7):

What you could use

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array with the same elements, but not necesserily all.
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns something for each loop, the result is an array with the same length as the source array.
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns nothing, but every element is processed, like above.
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) returns what ever you want.
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)/[`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) returns a boolean value.

But nothing from above is mutating the original array in question of length in situ.

I suggest to use a while loop, beginning from the last element and apply splice to the element, you want to remove.

This keeps the index valid and allows to decrement for every loop.

Example:

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    i = array.length;

while (i--) {
    if (array[i] % 2) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: How is this similar to `filter()`, `forEach()` and `map()`?

Comment: Am I correct in my reasoning that using [array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) like this has runtime O(array.length^2), and being slow iff I remove large parts of the array? I don't need to squeeze out every ounce of performance, but that is too slow for me.

Comment: while i would use filter, you have to take some drawbacks to your requirement, because of the in situ need.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I prefer torazaburo's O(n) solution.

Comment: Perseids, why do you suppose O(array.length^2)? I think this is the best solution, both because it's efficient, surgically removing elements in-place, but also because .splice works with reactive arrays, which is very useful.

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to add a third-party library, have a look at [lodash.remove](https://lodash.com/docs#remove):

```
predicate = function(element) {
  return element == "to remove"
}
lodash.remove(array, predicate)
```

Answer (score 2):

The currently selected answer works perfectly fine. However, I wanted this function to be a part of the Array prototype.

```
Array.prototype.filterInPlace = function(condition, thisArg) {
    let j = 0;

    this.forEach((el, index) => {
        if (condition.call(thisArg, el, index, this)) {
            if (index !== j) {
                this[j] = el;
            }
            j++;
        }
    })

    this.length = j;
    return this;
}
```

With this I can just call the function like so:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.filterInPlace(x => x > 2);
// [1, 2]
```

I just keep this in a file called Array.js and require it when needed.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly simplified TypeScript variant of user663031's answer:

```js
function filter_in_place<T>(array: Array<T>, condition: (value: T) => boolean)
{
    let next_place = 0;

    for (let value of array)
    {
        if (condition(value))
            array[next_place++] = value;
    }

    array.splice(next_place);
}
```

Using `splice()` instead of setting the `length` results in a 1.2x speedup for `1400000` iterations on Chrome 76.

Comment: Lest anyone tries in-place for to optimize for speed, it seems that array.filter(condition) is actually just as fast nowadays? Unless you're dealing with huge amounts of memory?

Comment: Obligatory unreadable one-liner :).

`const fip = (a, c, n = 0) => a.forEach(v => c(v) && (a[n++] = v)) || a.splice(n)`